# Find matrix such that: $Im(A) = Ker(A) = Im(A^T) = Ker(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming $Im(A) = Ker(A)$ implies A must be squared matrix.

Also $Ker(A) = Ker(A^T)$ might imply that $A = A^T$, i.e.: A might be symmetric (not sure if must be, but it's definitely easier to work with symmetric one).

Via *rank-nullity theorem*, I suppose that half of columns of A must linearly independent and n even number, since:

1. $dim(Im(A)) + dim(Ker(A)) = n$, and:
2. $dim(Im(A)) = dim(Ker(A))$

How about other properties to derive from initial conditions?

There is indirect suggestion that such real matrix might not exist, but complex matrix can exist.

How can I think about finding any such matrix? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $A^2=0$ you can use it?

Comment: Are you looking for all such matrices or for one of them?

Comment: @AnneBauval just one of them. Just wanted to restrict how can such matrix will look like.

Comment: Such a real matrix cannot exist indeed. Can you edit your post to make your "indirect suggestion" explicit? As for complex matrices, try $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$ and find the conditions on $a,b,c,d$ for $A^2$ to be $0,$ and then the simplest $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$ fulfilling these conditions.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! Didn't necessarily need $A^2 = 0$, but you suggestion helped. Such matrix might be: \begin{pmatrix}
i & -1 \\
-1 & -i
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Indeed! Well done. And what was your "indirect suggestion" for the non-existence of such *real* matrices? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1925661

Comment: @AnneBauval this is from exercise, but in foreign language. Basically it asked: "Can such real matrix exist? And complex one?" - so at least to me it indirectly suggested that matrix we are looking for is complex.

Comment: The link in my previous comment should enlighten you (plus the fact that if $A$ is real then $A^*=A^T$). If everything is now clear to you, maybe you could edit a [self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [AnneBauval](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/386889/anne-bauval):

Let's assume such matrix A exists. Let $n = 2$ and A is symmetric, then A is:

\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}

Then it follows:

\begin{array}{c}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a & b \\ 
   b & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   1 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
   a \\ b
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\end{array}

and:

\begin{array}{c}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a & b \\ 
   b & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   0 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
   b \\ d
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\end{array}

Because $Im(A) \subseteq Ker(A)$, it follows:

\begin{array}{c}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a \\ b 
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 
   b \\ d 
\end{pmatrix} 
\in
Ker(A)
\end{array}

Then it follows:

\begin{array}{c}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a & b \\ 
   b & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a \\ b 
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a^2 + b^2 \\ ab + bd 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\end{array}

and:

\begin{array}{c}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   a & b \\ 
   b & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
   b \\ d 
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
   ab + bd \\ b^2 + d^2 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\end{array}

From that we get:

$b = ia$, $d = -a$.

Let $a = i$, then $b = -1$ and $d = -i$.

So we get matrix A:

\begin{pmatrix}
i & -1 \\
-1 & -i
\end{pmatrix}